# Login, then logout on the first redirect

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

Every thing was running OK at local server: PHP 5.3.4, MySQL 5.1.49, Apache 2.2.17 and CakePHP 2.0.1.

But when I deployed to production server: PHP 5.3.5, MySQL 5.1.49, Apache 2.? and CakePHP 2.0.1.

... a weird error occurs. Login action is perfomed successfully, as I can verify on a my UserController `login()` action (and I have trace all stack calls). But just as its redirects to the /admin URL (that is a router path to a specifc action), the User is deleted from Session and it simply return to the "not logged" state. In adiction, the follow if-clause at AuthComponent just does not work very well, the `$this->flash` simply does not show anything.

(/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php : line 315 )

```
if (!$request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->flash($this->authError);
    $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', Router::reverse($request));
    $controller->redirect($loginAction);
    return false;
```

I'm using Auth / Acl component. I've configured as my answer at [CakePHP 2.0: ACL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967257/cakephp-2-0-acl-not-working/8177045#8177045)

I have no idea what is happening.

**EDIT:**
This morning I've noted that: the problem only happens, yet only on the remote server, in Chrome or Opera – both for Mac OSX. I've also tested the whole thing in other machines, Mac and Windows, and everything works ok. It's certainly something on my machine. Some settings in /etc/hosts perhaps.

Comment: I think its $this->Session->flash($this->authError);

Comment: Hi, Sudhir! Actually, the correct would be $this->Session->setFlash($this->authError);. The both approaches works OK at locahost, but none of them works on production server. :(

Comment: And real bad problem is that User get logged out in some point between   $controller->redirect($loginAction); and Acl validation on the new page. I'm sure the user is logged in exactly before redirect to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Session problem, try some basic tests. Set a value in a session using plain php functions, refresh the page and see if the data is still in the session. If not, then I would contact the host about it.

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar situation trying the cakeDC user plugin with cake2. If I exited the login() before the redirect() in the user_controller and echoed a html link to the page where $this->Auth->loginRedirect should have taken me, then the Auth component worked.

So this seems to be a Session issue in combination with the redirect.

I got it only working by changing the Session settings in the /Config/core.php using "use_trans_sid" enabled:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        //'defaults' => 'php'
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'CAKEPHP2',
        'ini' => array('session.use_trans_sid' => true)
    ));
```

Comment: 3wv, good point. I've tried to set and run, but didn't work. I'm going to check it carefully, also considering Kevin advice.